# Closing specific Browser tabs in Internet Explorer programmatically from AHK script

Tags: internet-explorer, autohotkey

I have an AHK script that creates multiple IE tabs, just for the purpose of visiting a number of URLs. At the end of the program, I would like to close all the tabs that have been opened, while leaving any tabs open that are not related to my program.

I've been struggling for a while to work out how to code this. WinClose seems to want to close IE down completely.

Would really value any assistance on this. I've been using AHK for a few years and it's my programming language of choice! I love what I can do with it! Especially how easy it is to compile code into a portable Executable!

Answer (score 0):

```
; Example is taken from here:
; http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/67438-navigate-to-javascript/#entry426699

VT_DISPATCH:=9, IID:="{332C4427-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}" ; IID_IHTMLWINDOW2
`(oIE:=ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")).visible:=True
oIE.navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327523/"
           . "closing-specific-browser-tabs-in-internet-explorer-programmatically-from-ahk-scr")

While, oIE.ReadyState<>4 Or oIE.Busy
   Sleep, 500

oWindow:=ComObj(VT_DISPATCH, ComObjQuery(oIE, IID, IID), 1)

; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741489(v=vs.85).aspx
newWin:=oWindow.open("http://www.autohotkey.com", "_blank")
While, % newWin.document.readyState!="complete"
   Sleep, 500

MsgBox, 262144, % A_LineNumber, % newWin.document.title

; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741361(v=vs.85).aspx
newWin.close
MsgBox, 262144, % A_LineNumber, % oIE.document.title
oIE.quit
ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be more than you are interested in doing, but you can use `COM` with Internet Explorer.  AutoHotkey has a `ComObjCreate()` function.  Using COM functions is like scripting Internet Explorer directly instead of hacking at it's GUI with window commands.

[Check out this SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430997/creating-a-script-that-fills-in-form-values-and-submits/17455659#17455659).

Also, here is an [Autohotkey thread for using COM](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic61509.html).

Here is a COM example from the docs:

```
ie := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible := true  ; This is known to work incorrectly on IE7.
ie.Navigate("http://l.autohotkey.net/")
```

[Here is Internet Explorer COM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084).